# After add the `redirect-getway autolocal ` to the `client.ovpn`, when I run the OpenVPN, the machine will get stuck

Tags: windows, openvpn

In my Windows Client, I use the bellow `client.ovpn` as the configuration file to run the OpenVPN:

```
client

proto udp
port 1194
dev tun

redirect-getway autolocal  # this is the issue cause

remote 43.224.204.19
resolv-retry infinite
persist-key
persist-tun

comp-lzo
verb 3
mute 20

<ca>
...
</ca>

<cert>
...
</cert>

<key>
....
</key>
```

But as long as I run it, the server will get stuck. I can not ping the Windows Client's IP any more.

Comment: Try `redirect-gateway`instead of `redirect-getway` - if you have the need for a routing gateway for your remote networks. If now, post more details /like subnets).